# dealing with special characters in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using **bulk API** to load data from a file and it is being imported correctly. The only problem is that if there is escape character like `\"` then it is imported as-is.

I will like to remove the slash and save the `result` dictionary as an object or nested document.

```
{
  "req_id": "25cc4d-9cd6-499f-a439-c9",
  "time": 109,
  "result": "{\"ReceiveReturn\":\"00\"}",
  "level": "info",
  "message": "time taken for request",
  "timestamp": "2015-04-17 23:59:59"
}
```

Is it possible to remove escape character?

Update:

Here is an example....

```
DELETE /test_index

POST /test_index/myid/
{"_uid":1234,"id":1,"name":"someName","newProperty":"some \" and some text\"Value","status":0}

POST /test_index/_search
```

As you can see in the results, there is a double quote. Is there anyway to remove all escaped characters before inserting the data?

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is correct. Actually Elasticsearch is storing the document the correct way using `"`. But as `"` is a JSON special character when you run the query using a HTTP tool you see it like `\"`. If you see your document using **JSONView** on Google Chrome you can see the real data like this:

```
{
  _index: "myindex",
  _type: "mytype",
  _id: "1",
  _score: 1,
  _source: {
    req_id: "25cc4d-9cd6-499f-a439-c9",
    time: 109,
    result: "{"ReceiveReturn" :"00"}",
    level: "info",
    message: "time taken for request",
    timestamp: "2015-04-17 23:59:59"
  }
}
```